# UILabel memory leak?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uilabel, nstimer

I have an NSTimer that fires off every second, and on that second I update a UILabel by setting the text property like so:

```
remainglbl.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i:%02i", var1, var2];
```

It works fine, but when I run it in xcode with Start With Performance Tool -> Leaks, it appears that the memory just keeps on climbing and climbing and climbing.

From my understanding, the string should be autoreleased (although I never see the memory decrease, or stop increasing).

Is this a memory leak? Is there a better way I can do this to keep my memory usage in check?

Thanks!

Update:  code to create the timer is as follows:

```
timeTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(changeTime:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

code to cleanup at timer finish is as follows:

```
[timeTimer invalidate];
[timeTimer release];
timeTimer = nil;
```

Anything wrong with this? I thought the memory might be freed once the timer finishes, but it doesn't.

Comment: Have you determined definitively that this line is the one responsible for the growing memory (i.e., commenting it out solves the problem)? Perhaps you are leaking somewhere else.

Comment: Yes, I have determined definitively that this lines is responsible.  Commenting it out solves the problem.

Comment: While unrelated, I think you're over-releasing timeTimer since you don't retain the instance when you create it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem was that I did not understand the performance tools.  Running with the Activity Monitor does not show increasing memory usage.

Comment: You were probably looking at "Total Allocations" which is the amount of memory allocated at some point even if it's since been released.  "Net Allocations" is the current memory usage.  The Leaks tool should also show you specifically which objects are getting leaked.

Answer (score 0):

Just out of curiosity, does the problem still occur if you use [remainingLbl setText: ] instead of setting the property? Your code looks fine... the memory should be cleaned up since stringWithFormat autoreleases the string.

One other thing to try: when you create threads in Objective-C you have to wrap all the code in an NSAutoreleasePool so that the things you create during the thread's execution are cleaned up. That shouldn't make a difference here as one should already exist - but it's worth a shot.

Comment: [remainingLbl setText:] performs exactly the same. 

Re: the NSAutoreleasePool - I'm not doing setting up the Autorelease pool, as I didn't think it was necessary.  My code to create the timer and delete it I added to my original post.